# Extract value by regular expression by using imacros eval

Tags: javascript, regex, match, eval, imacros

I get the following result after using this code `TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=class:stop-propagation&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM`

Output

```
<a class="stop-propagation" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&amp;longt=73.1290596&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra" id="map_link_27696295" onclick="stopPage=true; showPhotoMap('/propertyDetails/poiOnMap.html?lat=19.2412011&amp;longt=73.1290596&amp;projectOrProp=Project&amp;city=Thane&amp;includeJs=y&amp;type=poiMap2017&amp;address=Thane, Maharashtra');" style="outline: 1px solid blue;"><span class="icoMap"></span>Map</a>
```

I 'm trying to extract value for the variable called **longt** from the following code

```
SET longt EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/&(longt=.+?)&/)[1];")
PROMPT "{{longt}}"
```

But this is not giving me any output.
any suggestions on what modifications could be done to get the output, will be helpful for me.
Thanks

Comment: Use `longt=(.&?)&` or `longt=([^&]+)`.

Comment: for first "longt=(.&?)&" it didn't  worked and for the second it gave error "MacroSyntaxError: can not parse macro line 5: longt=([^&]+) (Error code: -910)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
longt=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OPrV5I/4/)

You can try this in imacro:

```
SET longt EVAL("var regex = /longt=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/g; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex);")
PROMPT {{longt}}
```

Comment: Updated my code according to your regex "  SET longt EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/&(longt=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)&/)[1];")  "  but that gave me error ---> "unterminated parenthetical, line: 3 (Error code: -1001)"

Comment: You havent closed the bracket for EVAL( .  Put an extra ')' at the end

Comment: Updated again with "  SET longt EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/&(longt=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))&/)[1];")   "    but still error ------>        ".match(...) is null, line: 6 (Error code: -1001)

Comment: I guess you need to escape backslash character '\' . I have updated the answer with imacro impolementation. Please note that you get more than one longitude in the result. Thus the results are being appended by space. you can modify as you want with it.

Comment: Just to get first I did [1] on your code..........  "  SET longt EVAL("var regex = /longt=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/g; var str = '{{!EXTRACT}}';str.match(regex)[1];")  " .................. Thanks alot for your time and effort

Comment: @deepesh, pleasure was mine... I get to learn imacro by the process